# mapping angle distribution to probability

Tags: probability

I am struggling with a very specific mathematics problem, which I think is highly non-trivial. Can somebody please help me?

Say that we have n angles which together sum into 2pi. These angles can all be different from each other.
Now we pick one angle at random with probability, such that **smaller angles are more likely to be picked than larger angles**.

Here are some examples how this would work in the limiting cases:

- if all angles are the same, probability of picking a particular one is 1/n
- if one angle is 0 while all others are non-zero, probability of picking the one that is zero is going to be 1 (or very close to 1)
- if two angles are zero while others are non-zero, probability of picking a zero angle is going to be close to 0.5

Is it possible to find a mapping that would map a particular distribution of angles (that together sum into 2pi) to probabilities
that would satisfy the above limiting cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Guess: The probability mapping could be $p_i = \displaystyle \frac {\displaystyle \frac {1} {\theta_i}} {\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n \frac {1} {\theta_j}}$ but this could not capture the case for $\theta_i = 0$ exactly.

Comment: Yes, I think this should work. Thanks!